# make : ifort : command not found

Tags: makefile, module, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to compile a Fortran code on a Linux Ubuntu machine and I'm getting the following error (in bold):

```
calcul@gpuserver:~/dp3D/src$ ./makedp3D
Do you want to use standard directory /home/calcul/bin/dp3D/ (y/n) ?y
Using  existing directory: /home/calcul/bin/dp3D/
objects will be in directory objects
objects for openmp option will be in directory objects_openMP
source directory: /home/calcul/dp3D/src/
main file for dp3D: /home/calcul/dp3D/src/main.f
Fortran compiler (ifort gfortran) ?: ifort
Will compile with ifort
Do you want to clean the object directory : (y/n) ?n
***********************************************
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_trs_tag_rm
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_trs_obj
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_bc
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_size
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_gas
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_rdf
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_cut
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_voxel
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_translate
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_mixture
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_xyz
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_raw
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_conduct
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3D_cubic
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Treating main.f90 to obtain 4 threads in dp3D_openMP
Treating trs_tag_rm.f90 to obtain 4 threads in dp3D_openMP
compiling a test version as /home/calcul/bin/dp3De
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  treating Make_dp3De
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
**make : ifort : commande introuvable
make: *** [Make_dp3De:16 : module_numeric_kind.o] Erreur 127
ifort -warn unused -static-intel -openmp  -gen-interfaces nosource -module modules -warn interfaces -c module_numeric_kind.f90 -o objects_openMP/module_numeric_kind.o
Treating main.f90 to obtain 4 threads in dp3D_openMP
Treating trs_tag_rm.f90 to obtain 4 threads in dp3D_openMP**
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Can someone help me in solving this issue?

I looked for many solutions on internet, but none really helped me.

Comment: The message is quite clear, `ifort` is not found. Is it installed on the machine?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Do not use tag [tag:fortran90], use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Read the short descriptions of the tags you are adding. Here, when showing the output of some Makefile, you should show the Makefile itself and also give us some details about your Fortran compiler. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You got a `make : ifort : Command not found` error message. That error message indicates that Intel Fortran compiler is possibly not installed  or it is not available to your Ubuntu user.

To install Intel Fortran compiler ifort in Ubuntu:

```
curl -Lo- https://apt.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS.PUB | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/oneapi-archive-keyring.gpg
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oneAPI.list <<< "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oneapi-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install intel-oneapi-compiler-fortran
```

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh > /dev/null
```

Comment: https://neelravi.com/post/intel-oneapi-install/ may be of use as well

Comment: You are assuming that ifort is not installed on the machine AND that the OP has admin privileges on the machines, but nothing tells us that. ifort may be installed but not in the patch of the OP's account and/or the OP may not have any admin privilege.